# Is there a way to read image metadata using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Does any one know of a way that I can read file metadata using node.js?  For example, I want to read the 'comment' attribute on the 'details' tab of a jpeg file (on a Windows machine).  See image below to understand what it is I am trying to read from the file's metadata.

[image]

Comment: Well, for this particular file you're seeing EXIF image metadata.  There is no generic file metadata, other than what is provided by the OS.  What are you trying to do exactly?  Just read EXIF for JPEG/TIFF, or something else?

Comment: I specifically need the 'Comments' field as shown in the image.  I don't know if that is provided by EXIF image metadata.  I guess this doesn't really need to be related to image files.  The 'Comments' field can be an attribute of other file types as well.  It just happens that I need to read it from a bunch of image files.

Comment: The comments field can be in other file types' metadata but not all.  For images, this data is stored via EXIF.  There is no generic metadata.

Comment: What would be the best way for me to extract this info from EXIF?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are a lot of NPM packages for reading EXIF data.  For example:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/exif-parser

```
var parser = require('exif-parser').create(buffer);
var result = parser.parse();
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Awsome!  Just what I needed.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi Brad, I try the above example in my application and I get `ReferenceError: buffer is not defined`. Is buffer something that I have to define beforehand?

Comment: @user95227 Yes, the buffer should contain the binary data of the image.

Comment: does this only applicable to image filetype? how about others like txt or doc?

Comment: @iCezz Text files don't have metadata.  Word documents don't use EXIF for metadata.  You'll need something else.

Comment: You are the best.

Comment: Can I have a custom HTML file or something with some kind of metadata stored?

Comment: @PaulaFleck Sure?

Comment: are there any packages that let you edit the metadata??

Comment: @oldboy It appears that there are several.  https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=exif%20write

Comment: i know. thats why im wondering if its possible (and if so how) to get the metadata of ***any file type*** in a windows environment?

Comment: @oldboy There is nothing that can work with *everything*/*anything*.

Comment: ok duly noted. is there anything that will allow me to get the extended attributes of font files specifically??

Comment: @oldboy Post a new question, and include what type of font files you're interested in, and what attributes you're looking for.  There are many font file formats.

Comment: only a few that matter: otf, ttf, woff, woff2, svg.