# Reading OSX Tags with NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have read through the Nodejs documentation but I can't seem to find a way to read in OSX tags with nodeJs.  Does nodejs have this functionality?

For example, I have a file called (test.txt) and I added a tag to the file called (testTag).  I want my nodejs script to read in the file and associated file tag.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no Node.js-module for this.
You can use the command line tool [tag](https://github.com/jdberry/tag) tho.

Install it with homebrew: `brew install tag`.
Then test if it works using `tag --version`.

The following code will look for a file `some_file_with_tags.md` in the same directory as the Node.js-script and output its Mac OS X Finder Tags:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var filename = "some_file_with_tags.md";

readTags(filename);

function readTags ( filename ) {
  var cmdArr = ["tag", "--list", "--no-name", filename];
  var cmd = cmdArr.join(" ");

  exec ( cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr ) {
    if ( error ) { console.error ( error ); }
    if ( stderr ) { console.log( stderr ); }
    if ( stdout ) {
      var tags = stdout.toString().split(",");
      console.log("Tags in file \"" + filename + "\": " + tags);  
    }   
  }); 
}
```

Comment: is there a way to include a brew-recipe like 'tag' in an npm-module. Maybe via a installation-script? So when somebody want's to install a npm-module containing 'brew tag' functionality, it automatically downloads on npm installation?

Answer (score -1):

These tags are not an OS X-specific feature, but are what's called [metadata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata).

https://www.npmjs.com/package/exif-parser allows you to read metadata.

See: [Is there a way to read file metadata using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091836/is-there-a-way-to-read-file-metadata-using-node-js)

Comment: This will only return image-metadata but not the Finder tags.