# get file metadata with owner information using node.js

Tags: node.js, metadata

I am trying to upload the files of any type(.txt, .doc, .xls, .jpg, .gif, .pdf, .csv, etc...) to Azure Blob storage. I want to extract all the metadata associated with that file uploaded and need to store the entire metadata information in MongoDB. I am using "multer-azure-blob-storage" npm to upload to the Azure Blob using Multer. I am not getting any metadata from Azure Blob.
Even when I am trying to fetch the metadata from my from request, I am able to fetch general metadata like last-modified, file-name, file-size, file-type, etc.. But not the owner/author information of the file. How can I fetch all the information of Details section properties of the below Image using node.js

[image]

How can I achieve my goal using node.js? What NPM's I need to use to get this information. Please help me out on this issue.

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091836/is-there-a-way-to-read-file-metadata-using-node-js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to read file metadata using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091836/is-there-a-way-to-read-file-metadata-using-node-js)

Comment: @Michele; @shaochuancs  Thanks for the response. But it will give the information only for Images, not for other types of documents.

Comment: did you find an NPM package to do this?